# Why is my code calculating incorrectly, it feels right to me?

Tags: solidity, erc-20

Why does this keep returning 0? And yes, it is above the claimtime. It does it for every address. I don't know what's wrong?

```solidity
function ViewDividendOwed(address _addr) public view returns (uint256) {
  uint256 _SavedDividend = _balances[address(this)].mul((_balances[msg.sender]).div(_totalSupply));  

  if (ClaimTime[_addr] + 2 minutes <= now) {
    return _SavedDividend;
  }
  else {
    return 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: Please include ALL the relevant code (an only the relevant code). What is `ClaimTime`? Where and how is `ClaimTime[_addr]` initialized? What is the value of `_balances[address(this)]` and `_balances[msg.sender]` and `_totalSupply` when you call the function? We're not supposed to guess all of that!

Comment: Are you in ganache?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code you are making the division first. My guess is that `_totalSupply` is larger than any balance so solidity will truncate the result to 0.

```
uint256 _SavedDividend = _balances[address(this)].mul(
    (_balances[msg.sender]).div(_totalSupply)
);
```

You have to multiply first and then divide.

```
uint256 _SavedDividend = (
    _balances[address(this)].mul(_balances[msg.sender])
).div(_totalSupply);
```

Comment: This was spot on! Thanks so much